# What's the genre of beat in the song

Tags: drums

I found a great song that I liked a lot and wanna reproduce the beat in it however don't even know what is the genre.

Can you please help me to reproduce it in FL?
I hear 2 kicks in a row and what goes next?
Sorry I am a beginner in drums :(

Beat starts at 0:11